# MongoDB Running Sum over 3 days per customer

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

I have the following json file (small sample) which consists of purchase records of 4 different customers across different dates. I am required to use MongoDB/nosql to identify which customers have made 0 new purchases over a consecutive period of at least 3 days.

In this case, customer DEF made 0 total purchases from 2020-05-12 to 2020-05-14 (3 consecutive days). Customer JKL also had 0 purchases from 2020-06-05 to 2020-06-08 (4 consecutive days). So my output should only contain customers DEF and JKL. How do I go about getting the output? Many thanks!

```
{"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-01", "new_purchase":222},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-02", "new_purchase":164},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-03", "new_purchase":134},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-04", "new_purchase":235},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-05", "new_purchase":190},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-11", "new_purchase":3},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-12", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-13", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-14", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-15", "new_purchase":1},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-28", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-29", "new_purchase":3},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-30", "new_purchase":17},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-31", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-08-01", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-04", "new_purchase":7},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-05", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-06", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-07", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-08", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-08", "new_purchase":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pipeline:

```
datapts = 3;

c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$sort: {"date":1}} // ensure dates are going smallest to largest                         

// Now organize by customer and create a date-ordered array of purchases:                 
,{$group: {_id: "$cust_id", items: {$push: {d: "$date", v: "$new_purchase"} } }}

,{$project: {"3daysum":

       {$filter: {
               // The $map expr is the heart of it.  It is basically doing                
               // a loop over the array of purchases, each time adding a slice            
               // of _datapts_ days worth of purchases.                                   
               // It is sitting "inside" $filter because we are only interested           
               // in 3 days running totals = 0                                            
           input: {$map: {
               input: {$range:[0,{$subtract:[{$size:"$items"}, (datapts-1)]}]} ,
               as: "z",
               in: {
                   tot: {$sum: {$slice: [ "$items.v", "$$z", datapts ] } },
                   d: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$items.d", {$add: ["$$z", (datapts-1)] } ]}
                       }
                   }},

           as: "zz",
           cond: {$eq: ['$$zz.tot',0]} // try changing this for fun                       
           }}
    }}

// Eliminate zero-length arrays.  Comment this out to see the diff:                       
,{$match: {$expr: {$gt: [ {$size: "$3daysum"}, 0 ] } }}

  ]);
```

will yield this result:

```
{
    "_id" : "DEF",
    "3daysum" : [
        {
            "tot" : 0,
            "d" : "2020-05-14"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "JKL",
    "3daysum" : [
        {
            "tot" : 0,
            "d" : "2020-06-07"
        },
        {
            "tot" : 0,
            "d" : "2020-06-08"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's a little more info than the OP asked for but it shows not only which customer had 3 (or anything you want) day no-purchase streaks, but also each day that such a streak occurred.